# R Studio - Seleccionar y extraer valores con los famosos brackets

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy utilizando R Studio y llevo un par de días dándole vueltas a como realizar los siguientes casos prácticos con los famosos brackets [] ó [[]], se me ocurre hacerlo con otro tipo de funciones como rownames o colnames pero me comentan que se puede hacer con los brackets:

**Seleccionar la primera y la última variable de tu marco de datos.**

En este punto lo único que he podido averiguar es que si lo hago con los brackets  [] me devuelve la tabla de las variables completas, es decir, me devuelve la primera variable que es Country (La tabla entera) y la quinta que es completed_vacunates pero no lo que necesito.

**#d. Extrae los tres primeros valores de la variable 2**
crisis_covid19[[2,3]]

**#e. Extrae el vector de la quinta observación**

De este no he podido averiguar nada porque no soy capaz de hacer los dos anteriores.

Las variables son (Por orden) : "country", "deaths", "sea", "size_country", "completed_vacunated".

El nombre del data frame es : crisis_covid19

Mi problema es que sigo pensando en que no se puede hacer unicamente con los brackets, ya que los brackets te devuelven la variable completa sin posibilidad de extraer datos precisos (Hasta donde yo he llegado).

Ruego puedan ayudarme.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido lperez01 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Trata de hacer más concreta tu pregunta por que no entiendo muy bien cual de todos los temas  es los que has tenido dificultad en resolver y (muy importante) agregar el código de lo que hayas intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es conceptual más quede uso de R.

Un data frame tiene filas y columnas. Cuando se usan los paréntesis cuadrados [,], lo que está a la izquierda de la coma implica filas. Lo que está a la derecha implica columnas.

Si se desean las dos primeras filas de la segunda columna se escribe crisis_covid19[1:2, 2]

Si se desean las filas 20 a 30 de la segunda columna se escribe crisis_covid19[20:30, 2]

Si se desean las filas 20 a 30 de todas las columnas, se escribe crisis_covid19[20:30, ], es decir, se deja en blanco a la derecha de la coma.

Lo usual es usar operaciones de filtrado para seleccionar las filas: crisis_covid19[crisis_covid19$country = 'Venezuela', ]

Si se desean todas las filas, se deja sin escribir a la izquierda de la coma.

Si se desean todas las filas de la columna 'country', se escribe: crisis_covid19[ , 'country']

Se puede escribir el número de la columna, pero se aconseja escribir el nombre de la columna.

Se puede combinar la selección de filas y de columnas:

crisis_covid19[crisis_covid19$country = 'Venezuela', c('deaths', 'sea', 'size_country', 'completed_vacunated')]